# MsBuild Target doesn't work

Tags: .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I want to change .csproj file to execute my target after I make publish on server from Visual Studio 2017.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>copy $(ProjectDir)\lib\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll $(ProjectDir)\bin</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>copy $(ProjectDir)\lib\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll $(ProjectDir)\bin</PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>  

  <ItemGroup>
    <OracleSourceFile Include="$(ProjectDir)\lib\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"/>
    <OracleDestinationFolder Include="$(ProjectDir)\bin"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="OracleTarget" AfterTargets="MSDeployPublish" >        
   <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(OracleSourceFile)"
        DestinationFolder="@(OracleDestinationFolder)">        
    </Copy>
  </Target>
```

But this doesn't work. I don't see in publish output that my target was executed. What I do wrong?

Comment: Do you use publish profile in Visual Studio?

Comment: @CodeNotFound Yes, I do

Comment: So I recommend you to read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files)

Comment: @CodeNotFound thank you for this idea. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the [Microsoft best practices about deploying web application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/), specially at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files) (which talks about Deploying Extra Files), I finally modified my .pubxml like below:

```
<Target Name="OracleCollectFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <OracleSourceFile Include="lib\**\*" />     
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(OracleSourceFile.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>bin\%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      OracleCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>

    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
      OracleCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

> MsBuild Target doesn't work

You may publish your project from `File System`. The target "MSDeployPublish" is not supported by the `File System`.

> "We currently do not support executing custom targets after publish
>   from VS for the file system protocol. If you publish from the command
>   line the target will be executed however."

So, we could use MSBuild command line to execute this custom target by specify the target, `/t:OracleTarget`:

```
msbuild "YourSolutionFile" /t:Build,OracleTarget /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=YourPublishFile.pubxml
```

**Besides**, another **solution** for this issue, you can use target `CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage` instead of `MSDeployPublish`:

```
  <Target Name="OracleTarget" AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage" >        
   <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(OracleSourceFile)"
        DestinationFolder="@(OracleDestinationFolder)">        
    </Copy>
  </Target>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunatly, AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage" didn't work for me. MSBuild command line is not really comfortable. So I used .pubxml as @CodeNotFound recomends.